# Do you know of a place or an API that lists all domains registered that day?

Tags: dns, whois

I am needing to be able to look at the new domains being purchased each day. Preferably free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is whois information, which is hard to find all in one place. If you're wanting to see only domains purchased today, [registered.today](http://registered.today) gives the list.

Comment: That service seems only to deal with gTLDs, but of course it is easy parsing their zonefiles and the OP did not specify which TLD(s). Some other TLDs, ccTLDs, also provide the same service in various degree.